# Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined in React JS inside map function

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, undefined, render, substr

While trying to render a functional component and trying to truncate a large paragraph on a map item using `item.biography.substr(0, 20)`.

I have tried different syntaxes without success. Will appreciate any help. Here is my component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from 'axios';
import $ from 'jquery';
//import "./styles.css";

function Instructor() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [data, setData] = useState(['a', 'b', 'c']);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);


  const loadMoreData = () => {
    setPage(page + 1);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        'http://www.localhost/ulearn/api/getInstructors',
      );
      setData(result.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> API FOR INSTRUCTOR COMPONENT </h1>
      {isLoading && <p>Wait I'm Loading comments for you</p>}

      {data.length !== 0 && (
        <button onClick={loadMoreData}>Load More Data</button>
      )}
      {data.map((item, index) => (

        <div className="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6" key={index}>
          <div className="instructor-box mx-auto text-center">
            <a href="{{ route(d.view, d.instructor_slug) }}">
              <main>
                <div className="col-md-12">
                  <h6 className="instructor-title">{item.first_name} 
                    {item.last_name}
                  `enter code here`</h6>
       <p> {item.biography.substr(0, 20)}  </p> 

                </div>
              </main>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

if (document.getElementById('instructor')) {
  ReactDOM.render(<Instructor />, document.getElementById('instructor'));
}
```

Comment: Did my answer solve your question?

Comment: Yes, indeed... I tried your answer and it worked... thanks a lot

Comment: @JoseMiguelSanchez Be sure to accept wentjun's answer by clicking the check mark to the left of it. This lets others know that you no longer need help on this, and it highlights the answer for others that might come across it in the future. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: When I click to accept the correct answer I get the following message : "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it is trying run the substring method on an `undefined` property? This could imply that `biogarphy` could be undefined.

Given that the initial state of `data` is `['a', 'b', 'c']`, it is certain that `biography` is `undefined` while waiting for the response from `fetchData()` in the `useEffect()` hook.

In that case, you might want to do a null/undefined check and conditionally run the statement with the `substr()` method only if `item.biography` has been populated with the response from the `useEffect` hook

```
{item.biography && item.biography.substr(0, 20)}
```

Answer (score 0):

if string can be null you'll get the error

change this line

```
<p> {item.biography.substr(0, 20)}  </p>
```

to

```
 {!!item.biography && (<p>{item.biography.substr(0, 20)}</p>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a check for biography is not undefined while using substr on it.

Also i suggest you to use .substring() as .substr is deprecated.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from 'axios';
import $ from 'jquery';
//import "./styles.css";

function Instructor() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [data, setData] = useState(['a', 'b', 'c']);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);


  const loadMoreData = () => {
    setPage(page + 1);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        'http://www.localhost/ulearn/api/getInstructors',
      );
      setData(result.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> API FOR INSTRUCTOR COMPONENT </h1>
      {isLoading && <p>Wait I'm Loading comments for you</p>}

      {data.length !== 0 && (
        <button onClick={loadMoreData}>Load More Data</button>
      )}
      {data.map((item, index) => (

        <div className="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6" key={index}>
          <div className="instructor-box mx-auto text-center">
            <a href="{{ route(d.view, d.instructor_slug) }}">
              <main>
                <div className="col-md-12">
                  <h6 className="instructor-title">{item.first_name} 
                    {item.last_name}
                  `enter code here`</h6>
       <p> {item.biography && item.biography.substring(0, 20)}  </p> 

                </div>
              </main>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

if (document.getElementById('instructor')) {
  ReactDOM.render(<Instructor />, document.getElementById('instructor'));
}
```

Comment: Great this answer is perfect and solved my problem... Extremely thankful.

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible that the content of `biography` is `undefined`, so you can add a check by conditionally rendering it to make sure it only displays the biography if `biography` contains a value or exists.

You can change

`<p> {item.biography.substr(0, 20)} </p>`

to

`{item.biography && <p> {item.biography.substr(0, 20)} </p>}`